# two processes with same execute time

Tags: concurrency, cpu, parallelism, process

Process A take 10 seconds to finish an execution. 
Process B take 10 seconds to finish an execution.

Is it possible to take 5, 8, 15 seconds to finish an execeution if they run stimulately.

Comment: You haven't really supplied enough information to answer the question. Under what circumstances are you running these processes? Multiple cores? On a typical workstation? An embedded device? What do the processes do? I/O? Pure calculations?

Comment: I got this question and it said only what i tell above. Is it possible?  If it's possible, how is it possible? and if not how is it Impossible?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)** "If your question... is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: ...I also wonder what's the point of [reposting prior deleted question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370744/run-2-processes-concurrently)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework with no effort expended on it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to tell from the information given. This reads like a very basic homework question or a sneaky trick question.

In the case of the basic homework question: no, A and B are separate processes and the amount of time each individually takes up can't be reduced by running them in parallel.

In the case of the sneaky trick question, if A and B both happen to rely upon process C that happens to take 9 seconds and when it finishes happens to return results such that parallel queries are responded to in parallel (but subsequent queries are reevaluated), then sure, it's possible to speed up the process with parallelization.